# How can I change the width of a tooltip container in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am making a very simple React application where I am in the need to display a tooltip on hover over the text...

```html
<OverlayTrigger
  placement="bottom"
  overlay={
    <Tooltip
      id="tooltip"
      style={{ width: "100%", wordBreak: "break-all" }}
    >
      thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotfilledincontiner
    </Tooltip>
  }
>
  <span>Hover over this text</span>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Before I had the problem of making the tooltip content fit into container, so I have used `wordBreak: "break-all"`, so it fits into the container box.

[A working example is here...](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-tooltip-button-modal-4ektt)

But now I got the requirement that the tooltip should display **horizontally long**. Now you can see it is making word breaks and the container is vertical with a fixed width... But how can I change the width of the tooltip container to make the text horizontally long in a single line?

From the above code, the text `thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotfilledincontiner` should be displayed in a single line with the tooltip expanded...

How can I change the width of the tooltip container in react bootstrap?

Comment: you want to width auto on single word whatever it will be long?

Comment: @Kumar, In my real application it will be a token which consists of  around 250 continuous  characters, so I want to display the entire string in a single line no matter how long the text is.. It should be displayed only in a single line like ```thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotfilledincontiner``` ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<Tooltip className="mytooltip" ...>
```

#### CSS

```css
.mytooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mytooltip > .tooltip-arrow {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution but If still not working you can try adding the css in index.css file.

Answer (score 3):

Add this CSS property in the below class.

```css
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: This was the key for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS content:

```css
.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  width: 7em;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

If you inspect it, you'll see the tooltip is placed after the item it's referencing, by default. So you can target it with CSS for widths and stuff.